# Meaning of 男性がときどき見せる[これって脈アリサイン]

Tags: meaning, particle-って

In the below sentence I translated the first part as "Men sometimes display" but cannot figure out the meaning of [これって脈アリサイン].

> 男性{だんせい}がときどき見{み}せる[これって脈{みゃく}アリサイン]

Comment: Are the brackets included in the original text?

Comment: I don't think the "first part" is really the first. Whether it was told in a previous part of a dialogue, or elsewhere in a guidebook for romance, it's simply missing. You can find the meaning of 脈ありin web dictionaries. サイン should be obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

これって”脈アリ”サイン　
＝Might this be the "there-is-a-chance" sign?

When you want to find a hot spring or a valuable metals, you have to check 水脈 (the hot water pathway underground) or 鉱脈 (metalliferous vein) in advance.

脈がある means that there is such a 脈, which is something good, positive, and welcomed.

Now in the modern colloquial Japanese, "脈アリ" means that **there is the possibility that the person likes you, has a positive feeling toward you, has a date with you, or becomes your lover.**

男性がときどき見せる[これって脈アリサイン]

***[The sign of positive feeling toward you, maybe,] that men show you sometimes***